# Exception in thread “main” java.util.InputMismatchException

Tags: java

// gets input number ,then work out if it is prime ?
  // gets input from keyboard

```
   package basicjava; 

   import java.util.*;

   public class Primes {

   public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner scanner = new Scanner("System.in");
    System.out.println("Enter a Positive Integer Please  ");
    int userInput = scanner.nextInt();

    int potentialFactor = 2;
    while (userInput % potentialFactor != 0 ) {
        potentialFactor++;
    }
    if (potentialFactor == userInput) {
        System.out.println("the number is prime");
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("the number is not prime");
    }

}
```

}

// if the number is prime it is printed , otherwise 
// message " the number is not prime " is printed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem lies here:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner("System.in");
```

There are more than one way to create a `Scanner`. One way is to pass in a string, like you did here. Then the scanner will just try to scan the string. After some lines you asked the scanner for an integer. The scanner looks at the string "System.in" and says "I see no integer here" and throws an exception.

Another way to create a `Scanner` is to pass in an input stream. It will then try to read from the input stream. This is what you *should* do:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
```

Notice how I removed the `""`. This means that `System.in` now refers to `in`, an instance of input stream that represents the console's input.

Answer (score 0):

The [`Scanner#nextInt`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextInt())

```
 @throws InputMismatchException
*         if the next token does not match the <i>Integer</i>
*         regular expression, or is out of range
```

Also, you can rewrite your code to:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in); // there is a System class in java.lang
```